# jQuery on click target data 'id' + 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to find a way to target on click a data id by adding one or subtracting one from the current one.

```
$(".next-project").click( function () {

    $( '#project-container' + $(this).data( ('id') + 1 ) ).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000).addClass('project-flex');

    $('.wrapper').css('opacity', '.32');
});
```

In my html my divs have the data ids such as

```
<div class="project-container" id="project-container1"></div>
<div class="project-container" id="project-container2"></div>
<div class="project-container" id="project-container3"></div>
```

While each div looks like:

```
 <div class="project-container" id="project-container2">
  <div class="project-side-left">
    <div class="close-project">
      <img src="img/icons/icon-x.svg" alt="Close">
    </div>
    <p class="project-category">Web Design</p>
  </div>
  <div class="project-wrapper">
    <div class="project-top-bar">
      <a class="previous-project">Previous Project</a>
      <button class="next-project">Next Project</button>
    </div>
    <img class="project-img" src="img/projects/marz-01.png">
    <h2>Marz</h2>
    <p>project background</p>
    <img class="project-img" src="img/projects/cacaosuyo-01.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to add or subtract from the data id value? or is it simply a string right now and need to be converted to a number first? I'm trying to change what project-container is being displayed in the same spot. When the button with the class 'next-project' is clicked, the current project will hide and the next one becomes displayed.

*solved*
Using this function seems to work.

```
$(".next-project").click( function () {
    let next_id = '#' + $(this).parents('.project-container[id]:eq(0)')
            .attr('id')
            .replace(/(\d+)$/, function (s)
            {
                return parseInt(s) + 1;
            });
    $(next_id).addClass('project-flex');

});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Generally when the data attribute contains a numeric value `data()` will return number type

You have a syntax issue though

```
$('#project-container' + $(this).data( ('id') + 1 ) )
```

Should be

```
 $( '#project-container' + ($(this).data('id') + 1 ) )
                                       // ^^ only property name inside ()
```

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
$('.project-container[id] .next-project').click(function ()
{
    let next_id = $(this)
        .parents('.project-container[id]:eq(0)')
        .attr('id')
        .replace(/(\d+)$/, function (s)
        {
            return parseInt(s) + 1;
        })
    ;

    $(next_id)
        .show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000)
        .addClass('project-flex')
    ;

    $('.wrapper').css('opacity', '.32');
});
```

Comment: `data('id')` is not same as `id` property

Comment: @charlietfl he didn't set `data-id` or `.data('id', value)`, so  i think he's `data id` is mean `attr id`

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted that I do have `class=".next-project"` in my html. I'm trying to change the displayed div to become the next project. I'm trying to to change it's parent().parent().parent().

Comment: @CamO'Brien `.parents('.project-container[id]:eq(0)')`